# how to give arguments to a python function in a nuke expression?

Tags: python, expression, tcl, nuke

I'm trying to put a python function in a expression node expression.
The following syntax works perfectly well:

```
[python testMe()]
```

My question is about how giving my function some arguments.
For example, how can I give the pixel red color, like in tcl : `r(x,y)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be too closely related to tcl.

Comment: It seems Nuke has both Python and TCL support. I believe the OP's question is a valid one.

Comment: Fair enough.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think what you're trying to do is impossible because of the evaluation order of knob expressions vs. the pixel processing expressions.

**tl;dr:** The TCL expressions in the Expression node's knobs are being evaluated **before** the variables you're after are actually available.

### The Longer Version

*This glosses over or otherwise simplifies many things about Nuke's operator evaluation in order to try and address the original question more concisely.*

Expressions on knobs (i.e. those in square brackets, or set using right-click -> "Add Expression...") are evaluated at the beginning of the operator's processing (during what you can call the "knob store" phase) before any kind of pixel processing starts. This step generates the actual (numeric) values that are stored by the internal C++ `Knob` objects, in order to make the values available for use during pixel processing. This expansion is done transparently by most built-in knob types so that a plugin developer doesn't have to worry about doing it themselves in their operator code.

One way to see a little of what's going on is to evaluate a Nuke expression in the context of one of these knobs outside of any rendering context:

```python
nuke.tcl('in Expression1.expr2 {return [expression x]}')
```

This uses the Nuke TCL command `in` to set the evaluation context for an expression to one of the pixel expression knobs. Then, the `expression` command (not to be confused with TCL's `expr` command), evaluates the given string as a normal Nuke knob expression (knob expressions use what is essentially a restricted subset of TCL's `expr` grammar that only operates on float values and does knob and variable resolution for strings like `Grade1.blackpoint`).

You'll notice that this `nuke.tcl` call does actually return a value, but unfortunately, that value is the current frame number. If you replace `x` with `y` in the expression... you get 0. In other words, the pixel coordinates are not available in the knob's expression context during the "knob store" phase (when Nuke will be expanding your TCL expression(s)).

When the Expression node is actually processing pixels, the text values from each expression knob are expanded by the operator in an expression context that has the `x` and `y` variables set to the coordinates of the pixel that is currently being processed.

Anyway, I know this may be a bit technical and long-winded, but I hope it helps explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for standard knobs, such as floating point sliders:

```
[python ["testMe([value userknob])"]]
```

Sample Python function:

```
def testMe(val):
    return val
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work with the special hooks as part of the Expression node. That seems to be an issue with Nuke -> Tcl, rather than Tcl -> Python. If you figure that one out, let me know!

Here's a node you can copy and paste:

```
Expression {
 expr0 "\[python \[\"testMe(\[value userknob])\"]]"
 name Expression2
 selected true
 xpos -648
 ypos -554
 addUserKnob {20 User}
 addUserKnob {7 userknob}
 userknob 0.47
}
```

Comment: `[python "testme([value userknob])"` might work, but I've not got things set up to test…

Comment: Ah, so it does. Shows what I know of tcl (zero)! Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys. This is answering my question though not my problem as my args are not knobs values. Let's say I would like to compute per pixel the average value of the 8 surrounding pixels in my python function, is it possible to give my function the pixel values while  iterating through the image pixels ? ( I expect this can be done in a Tcl expression but then it's an exemple ).

Comment: @Pic, sorry it's not 100% yet. If you're able to figure it out in Tcl, I bet we can figure out how to get that into Python. I'll keep looking too